# Shell script non - hardcoded string in awk

Tags: string, bash, shell, awk

So, in order to write all the processes of a specific user I tried to use this code:

```
ps aux --sort -rss | awk '$1 == "$(whoami)"'
```

When I hardcode my username into it, it works perfectly.
Also, I tried to substitute "" with '', // and blanks, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: it was indeed, fix'd

Comment: To explain what's wrong : your `awk` command is surrounded in single-quotes. This is a good thing for the `$1` which should *not* be expanded by bash but left as-is to be handled by `awk`. This is however a bad thing for `$(whoami)`, which should be expanded by `bash` to your user. An alternative to the (better) solutions posted would be something like `... | awk "\$1 == $(whoami)"` where the `$` of `$1` is escaped so that it isn't interpreted as a variable, while the subshell is expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you in same(as per OP's approach).

```
ps aux --sort -rss | awk -v who="$(whoami)" '$1==who'
```

Comment: I recommend quoting the `$(whoami)` subshell, the username could contain a space or some other character from IFS which would break the command.

Comment: @Aaron, sure, usually I do. I have edited it now. in `awk`'s variable.

Comment: That seems unlikely in this particular scenario; `whoami` should return a single token. But proper quoting doesn't harm, and makes the example easy to adapt to scenarios where it does matter.

Comment: @Aaron Though quoting is not necessary for bash assignments, in this is case it is much recommended.

Comment: @down voter, please add reason for down voting. It discourage if you don't mention the reason for it :(

Answer (score 6):

`ps -u $(whoami) -o user,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,comm --sort -rss`

way without `awk`